# Check if array elements are consecutive without order

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int n = arr.Length;
bool result = areConsecutives(arr, n);
if (result == true)
    MessageBox.Show("Yes");
else
    MessageBox.Show("No"); 

static bool areConsecutives(int[] arr, int n)
{
    int first_term = int.MaxValue;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < first_term)
            first_term = arr[j];
    }

    int ap_sum = (n * (2 * first_term + (n - 1) * 1)) / 2;

    int arr_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr_sum += arr[i];

    return ap_sum == arr_sum;
}
```

This works fine even if I change my array to this:

```
int[] arr = { 4, 2, 1, 3 }
```

The problem/question is what can I do to check if the array elements are consecutive, for example if I have the following array:

```
int[] arr = { 4, 8, 12, 16 }
```

They are consecutive/multiple by 4 and also the array can be in this way:

```
int[] arr = { 16, 4, 8, 12 }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "consecutive"? That each element in the array is some other element plus a constant (except the lowest element)?

Comment: @canton7 By consecutive/multiple I mean for example 1, 2, 3, they are consecutive by 1. 3, 6, 9, 12,  they are by 3 or, 75, 125, 150, 50, they are by 25, etc.

Comment: does "consecutive" means "we can re-order items such that we have an *arithmetic progression*", e.g. `3, 5, 11, 9, 7` can be put as `3, 5, 7, 9, 11`? Or (more strict) "consecutive" means that all items can be represented as `const * k` where `k = 1, 2, ..., n`?

Comment: By "consecutive" do you mean the elements, when sorted, are evenly spaced?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, a way to do it maybe is to order the array elements from min and max and then check if they are consecutive/multiple of the difference between two first items, in your example the consecutive/multiple is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not looking for an arithmetic progression and just simply want whether the numbers are consecutively growing then you could do something like this. Just check whether the previous value is ever greater than the current.

```
var isConsecutive = true;
var numbers = new[] { 1.3, -1, 0, 1.5 };
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i - 1] > numbers[i])
    {
        isConsecutive = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @User1899289003 If this is actually the answer, you expressed your question very badly...

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
var vals = new[] { 125, 25, 50, 75, 100 };
Array.Sort(vals);
bool arithmetic = vals.Zip(vals.Skip(1), (x, y) => y - x).Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

We start by sorting the array. Then we take each pair of elements (so take 25 and 50, then 50 and 75, etc) and find the difference between them. Then we take the number of different differences we found, and see if that's 1: if it is, our elements are evenly spaced.

---

Here's another:

```
var vals = new[] { 125, 50, 75, 100 };
Array.Sort(vals);
bool areArithmetic = true;
if (vals.Length > 1)
{
    int difference = vals[1] - vals[0]; 
    for (int i = 2; i < vals.Length; i++)
    {
        if (vals[i] != vals[0] + i * difference)
        {
            areArithmetic = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here we sort the list again, and then loop through the sorted list. We find the difference between the first two elements, then check that every subsequent element is an appropriate multiple of that difference.

Comment: This seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if this is going to work if I use negative or decimal numbers. For example int[] array = { 1.3, -1, 0. 1.5 }.

Comment: `{ 1.3, -1, 0, 1.5 }` isn't an arithmetic progression... It should handle negative numbers, but floats are a tricky beast that are going to make *any* approach hard

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using `Array.Sort` and simple `for` loop, without `System.Linq`

```cs
int[] arr = { 16, 4, 8, 12 };
Array.Sort(arr);

bool result = true;
for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
    if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] != arr[i + 1] - arr[i])
    {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this: determine which values are needed, and then check if `arr` contains each of those values.

```
var min = arr.Min(); // This is also the expected "gap" between elements
var max = min * arr.Length;
var isOK = min > 0;
for (var i = min; i <= max && isOK; i += min)
{
    if (!arr.Contains(i))
        isOK = false;
}
Console.WriteLine(isOK ? "Consecutive" : "Not consecutive");
```

**Working demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/YpSXwF

---

Or if `0` and negative values are also allowed:

```
var min = arr.Min();
var gap = arr.Where(x => x > min).Min() - min;
var max = min + gap * (arr.Length - 1);
var isOK = gap > 0;
for (var i = min; i <= max && isOK; i += gap)
{
    if (!arr.Contains(i))
        isOK = false;
}
Console.WriteLine(isOK ? "Consecutive" : "Not consecutive");
```

**Working demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3jGP5

Comment: You'd be better off using a HashSet, or linq's Except -- that will turn this from quadratic into linear

Comment: Also note that the sequence might not have to start at its lowest value, necessarily, which your code assumes

Comment: @canton7 HashSet can indeed be used as an optimization, but doing so does not change the *logic* (the algorithm) in any way. About your second comment: incorrect, if you try the demos then you will see that they use and work for any order of elements.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: I wasn't talking about the *order* of elements, I was talking about e.g. `[4, 6, 8]` (where here the sequence does not start at `2`). You fixed this in your edit, though, by not assuming that the gap is the same as the minimum element.